# Playing embedded resource mp3 file

Tags: c#, winforms, mp3, embedded-resource

I'm trying to play a mp3 file, which is embedded in my c# application (winforms) but with no result. I don't want to create a file from the resource and play it. I've searched the internet but haven't found any working examples. All of them are creating a file from the resource and save it, then pass the file path to mci or wmp. Is it possible to pass a stream?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    private static extern long mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, StringBuilder lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Stream fileStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("mymp3.mp3");
        string command = "open" + fileStream not filePath + "type MPEGVideo alias MyMp3";
        mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
        command = "play MyMp3";
        mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you then trying to use this `filestream`?

Comment: I've updated my code, I want to use the stream instead of file path. command won't be a string than, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You'd eed to convert the MP3 into a playable format. You already have the MP3 stream, so you can then use something like NAudio to convert to a WAV stream. Once you have done this you can use the    SoundPlayer class. You get something like the following.

```
using (Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(fileStream)) {  
    using (WaveStream pcmStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(reader)) {   
        SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(pcmStream);  
        player.Play();  
} } }
```