# playing an mp3 resource with mciSendString

Tags: c++, winapi, mp3

i have an mp3 file compiled right into my executable as a resource.
now using the functions FindResource, LoadResource, and LockResource, i can easily acquire a pointer to the resource buffer.
but how am i going to play the mp3 sound now?

if the `mp3` file was an external file, not as a resource, I could have played it using the `mciSendString` function, as follows:

```
mciSendString(
L"open sounds\\alban.mp3 type mpegvideo alias song1",
NULL, 0, 0);

mciSendString(
L"play song1 from 0",
NULL, 0, 0);
```

but unfortunately, the `mp3` sound is in my memory, and not as an external file.
is there still a way to play the mp3 sound with `mciSendString`?
if not, how can i play the sound from memory.

additional note:
If it was a wave sound, i could have easily played it with the PlaySound function.
but PlaySound is not for mp3.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002046/playing-embedded-resource-mp3-file

Comment: If it's possible convert it and embed it as wav rather than mp3. If the result file is large, write it to a temporary directory using [`GetTempPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [`GetTempFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Just make sure the temporary file extension is mp3.